# MongoDB 3.2 - how to project sub attributes of an object with variable attribute names

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I need to get this result:
name, and the ids inside elementsInPanel.
The problem that I find is that for all objects, the panels have the info in id keys, that are always different. I didn't find a way to do something like $unwind: "$panels.*.elementsInPanel"

Is that possible? If not, how would you do it?

```
{
    "name" : "A Dashboard",
    "panels" : {
        "54ca95f3ae644d531b29fa9b" : {
            "elementsInPanel" : [ 
                "541c5e7af0a8c43210f4732d", 
                "541c7a73762ac93d1734f560", 
                "541e0f3f591450a82b9dadfc", 
                "541e0f8b591450a82b9dae09", 
                "546ccfffb849b58e4bb91bf7", 
                "54700886a587aaec54f22058"
            ]
        },
        "54ca95f3ae644d531b29fa9c" : {
            "elementsInPanel" : [ 
                "541c5e7af0a8c43210f4732d", 
                "541c7a73762ac93d1734f560", 
                "541e0f3f591450a82b9dadfc", 
                "541e0f8b591450a82b9dae09", 
                "546ccfffb849b58e4bb91bf7", 
                "54700886a587aaec54f22058"
            ]
        }
    },
    "id" : ObjectId("5424bef7e880605e4d18af76")
}
```

Comment: Is this data structure correct? Shouldn't `panels` also be an array?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct data structure

Comment: With MongoDB 3.2 using the aggregation framework, you cannot. There simply are not the available features to "traverse document keys" in the manner you are asking. MongodB 3.4.4 introduces `$objectToArray` to "coerce" the named keys into an "array". Alternately you can use mapReduce for whatever your "aggregation" actually is ( which you do not state in your question ), or indeed take the cue from the fact that the only method is "coercion to an array" and then instead actually store as an array, instead of using named keys.

Comment: @NeilLunn That was what I actually thought. I couldn't find a function that could help me on doing that. Unfortunately I cannot change that structure. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, you "can" use mapReduce for "traversing keys" since that has always been a functional part of JavaScript, however your question completely lacks any explanation of what exactly you need to do. Also, stating "I cannot change the structure" is not really a wise course of action. Any inspection requires "coercion to an array" as mentioned. The cost of "coercion" is of course "time". So keeping this structure means that any such operation ( new version of MongoDB or not ) will always run slower than where the data was already in an array.

Comment: Point being that "cannot" usually means *"I don't want to spend the time"*, however the outcome is *"all queries will take more time"*. So either way, there is time spent. Either in fixing to a more appropriate structure, or by leaving it as it is and having non-optimal performance as a result of the present structure. That's the point I am trying to get across.

Comment: @NeilLunn I don't have control on the database structure. I can only use it. thank you for your comments